# Где реализовать поиск в реальном времени?

Tags: frontend, backend, search

Делаю поиск в реальном времени, т.е. при изменении текстового поля меняется количество отображаемых данных.

Где правильнее реализовать сам метод, который будет выполнять поиск: на беке или фронте?

Я так понял, что при большом количестве людей будет выполняться много запросов на сервер, что не есть хорошо, вот поэтому смущает меня вариант делать это на бекенде.

Comment: Ну а вариант на фронте подразумевает скачивание всех данных, необходимых для поиска, на этот самый фронт. Приемлемо ли это в вашем конкретном случае на ваших конкретных данных — вам лучше знать

Comment: В общем случае, если у вас 10 пользователей и миллиард данных, то поиск на бэке. Если миллиард пользователей и 10 данных - на фронте. Если поиск позволяет (например, ищем "123" после "12") - не делайте новый запрос на бэк, т.к. новый набор данных уже включен в прошлый.

Comment: + Если данные не супер динамические, есть статика, то можно кэшировать на сервере ответы и не ходить в БД. Можно какую то часть данных кэшировать на стороне клиента вводим 1 -> 12 -> 123 -> 12(Это было и врят ли поменяется, можно из кэша достать и отобразить)